# Completely Fair Scheduler (CFS): vruntime of long running processes

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler, cfs

If vruntime is counted since creation of a process how come such a process even gets a processor if it is competing with a newly created processor-bound process which is younger let say by days?

As I've read the rule is simple: pick the leftmost leaf which is a process with the lowest runtime.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [kernel documentation for CFS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt) kind of glosses over what would be the answer to your question, but mentions it briefly:

> In practice, the virtual runtime of a task
>   is its actual runtime normalized to the total number of running tasks.

So, `vruntime` is actually normalized. But the documentation does not go into detail.

### How is it actually done?

Normalization happens by means of a `min_vruntime` value. This `min_vruntime` value is recorded in the CFS runqueue (`struct cfs_rq`). The `min_vruntime` value is the smallest `vruntime` of all tasks in the rbtree. The value is also used to track all the work done by the `cfs_rq`.

You can observe an example of normalization being performed in CFS' [`enqueue_entity()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L2999) code:

```
2998 static void
2999 enqueue_entity(struct cfs_rq *cfs_rq, struct sched_entity *se, int flags)
3000 {
3001         /*
3002          * Update the normalized vruntime before updating min_vruntime
3003          * through calling update_curr().
3004          */
3005         if (!(flags & ENQUEUE_WAKEUP) || (flags & ENQUEUE_WAKING))
3006                 se->vruntime += cfs_rq->min_vruntime;
3007 
3008         /*
3009          * Update run-time statistics of the 'current'.
3010          */
3011         update_curr(cfs_rq);
...
3031 }
```

You can also observe in [`update_curr()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L701) how `vruntime` and `min_vruntime` are kept updated:

```
701 static void update_curr(struct cfs_rq *cfs_rq)
702 {
703         struct sched_entity *curr = cfs_rq->curr;
...
713 
714         curr->exec_start = now;
... 
719         curr->sum_exec_runtime += delta_exec;
... 
722         curr->vruntime += calc_delta_fair(delta_exec, curr);
723         update_min_vruntime(cfs_rq);
... 
733         account_cfs_rq_runtime(cfs_rq, delta_exec);
734 }
```

The actual update to `min_vruntime` happens in the aptly named [`update_min_vruntime()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L457) function:

```
457 static void update_min_vruntime(struct cfs_rq *cfs_rq)
458 {
459         u64 vruntime = cfs_rq->min_vruntime;
460 
461         if (cfs_rq->curr)
462                 vruntime = cfs_rq->curr->vruntime;
463 
464         if (cfs_rq->rb_leftmost) {
465                 struct sched_entity *se = rb_entry(cfs_rq->rb_leftmost,
466                                                    struct sched_entity,
467                                                    run_node);
468 
469                 if (!cfs_rq->curr)
470                         vruntime = se->vruntime;
471                 else
472                         vruntime = min_vruntime(vruntime, se->vruntime);
473         }
474 
475         /* ensure we never gain time by being placed backwards. */
476         cfs_rq->min_vruntime = max_vruntime(cfs_rq->min_vruntime, vruntime);
...
481 }
```

By ensuring that `min_vruntime` is properly updated, it follows that normalization based on `min_vruntime` stays consistent. (You can see more examples of where normalization based on `min_vruntime` occurs by grepping for "normalize" or "min_vruntime" in `fair.c`.)

So in simple terms, all CFS tasks' `vruntime` values are normalized based on the current `min_vruntime`, which ensures that in your example, the newer task's `vruntime` will rapidly approach equilibrium with the older task's `vruntime`. (We know this because the documentation states that `min_vruntime` is monotonically increasing.)

Comment: @mazuel After a half of the year I'm finally getting this. ;)
I searched for normalize in 'fair.c' and found [place_entity()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L3135) as a another place where min_vruntime is used to update se->vruntime. So I've got the picture. Now what is left is the actual logic. When exactly vruntime of a task is updated by assigning a value of min_vruntime to it, when it is only incremented by min_vruntime and why it is sometime decremented by min_vruntime as in [task_waking_fair()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L4727)? :]